# Fastest way to determine whether an integer is within the top two biggest integers out of 4 user inputed integers without using && or ||

Tags: java, boolean

This method returns 'true' if A is the biggest or second biggest of the 4 numbers.  'false' otherwise. While I did use &&, my assignment states that for this method I am NOT allowed to use either && or ||.

Here's the way I did using `&&` and `||`. How can I do it without that?

```
public static boolean isAtop2spots1(int A, int b, int c, int d)
{
    boolean test = false;

    if ((A>b) && (A>c))
    {
        test = true;
    }
    else if ((A>d) && (A>c))
    {           
        test = true;
    }
    else if ((A>b) && (A>d))
    {
            test = true;
    }
            return test;

}
```

Comment: use nested if for this purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested `if`s:

```
public static boolean isAtop2spots1(int A, int b, int c, int d) {
    if (A > b) {
        if (A > c) return true;
        if (A > d) return true;
    }
    if (A > c) {
        if (A > b) return true;
        if (A > d) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What if.... `b` is the largest number while `A` is the 2nd largest?

Comment: Personally, I would rather use an `int` counter to make sure there is *at most* one element that is larger than `A`. This would work, but it could take some effort to figure out what is going on when you come back later on.

Comment: @Jai that would be great. And I agree it doesn't look like a good solution. Unfortunately this question is closed otherwise we might have seen some interesting answers.